# https works on webmin but not on domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, webmin, apache2

I got an issue with the https request, when it comes to the access webmin, is working fine even the certificates are working pretty good. when i try to access the domain using https is not working. I am using an Amazon Web Service. on Aws the i have the 443 open. When i `curl https://localhost:443` i got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 443: Connection refused`

Website : http://tituslucian.com Webmin : https://tituslucian.com:2011/

/etc/apache2/sites-available

```
 <VirtualHost *:*>


    ServerAdmin adascaliteilucianfelix@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tituslucian.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerName tituslucian.com

<Directory /var/www/html/tituslucian.com>


        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Can someone help me with this, or at least give me some hints/ideas ?

Comment: not quite sa sme thing, but i will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can start troubleshooting with below.

**1.** At first, See if your domain is configured to listen on port 443 in apache configuration.

Webmin is working with https properly, since it installs the necessary configurations itself.

You have used `*.*` and i am not sure if that will work.

**2.** Add SSL certs and keys directives properly in Apache configuration.

**3** .Cross check firewall allow list on the server even though you have allowed 443 in AWS security group.

EDIT: Port 443 doesn't seems to be open your server, a quick nmap scan can check this.

let us know your findings on this and we will debug this error further.

Comment: The problem is almost certain to be that either nothing is listening on the relevant IP:Port or a firewall is configured to return `icmp-port-unreachable` as per the linked duplicate above.